# Why is my element.classList.add working but toggle is not working?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to add/remove a class upon button click. For some reason, `classList.toggle` will not work but `classList.add` works fine.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.view-now').forEach( function (){
    this.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        const property = e.target.closest('.property');
        property.classList.toggle('expand');
    });
});
```

Comment: your code seems to work fine, can you please share a codepen with the issue replicated?

Comment: @NarenMurali Naren. It can be viewed here: https://codepen.io/dmking0728/pen/abbroYj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please change the `this` in the `forEach` since its referring to the document context instead of the specific `a` tag. In the original code, the page was listening for a click on the entire page, which was causing the issue you were facing.

```
/**** Your JS Here ****/
//define DOM element
//this makes whatver you click dissappear both boxes
document.querySelectorAll(".view-now").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const property = e.target.closest(".property");
    property.classList.toggle("expand");
  });
});
```

[<kbd>`Codepen`</kbd>](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/xxxNbBX)